# SVG - why SVG filters are declared to be supported at 97.02% while specific SVG filter seem to be barely supported at 49, 50%?

Tags: svg

See here:

- [SVG filter](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20filter): 97,02%
- SVGs'  [feBlend](https://caniuse.com/#search=feblend), [feImage](https://caniuse.com/#search=feimage),  [feGaussianBlur](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-svg_elements_fespecularlighting), [feSpecularLighting](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-svg_elements_fespecularlighting), [feMerge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-svg_elements_femerge): around 50% support, like several other SVG's filters elements

how it is possible? what is the real browsers' rate support ?

thanks for any hint

Comment: There is missing data e.g. Whether safari supports filters (it does). You could click on the links and add the missing data if you know the answers.